# How to set "Send reminder to" to "All attendees" via import an ics file Office 365

Tags: outlook, office365, icalendar

Is there any way to set "Send reminder to" to "All attendees" in Office 365 Calendar?

I have tried to add "ATTENDEE" part into "VALARM", but still can't set this value correctly.

[image]

Here is my test ics file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
... 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
... 
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CUTYPE=INDIVISUAL;PARTSTAT=TENTATIVE;
 CN=Name:mail@mail.onmicrosoft.com
...
BEGIN:VALARM ACTION:EMAIL
TRIGGER;VALUE=DURATION:-PT2H
DESCRIPTION:email reminder
SUMMARY: Reminder
ATTENDEE:mailto:mail@mail.onmicrosoft.com 
END:VALARM 
END:VEVENT 
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Google RFC5545 VALARM

Comment: @anmari Thanks for your suggestion. I have checked RFC5545 document, and try to add "ATTENDEE" part into ics file, but I still can't set the value of "Set reminder to" to "All atendees". It seems a bug of Office 365.

Comment: Judith, It may be intentional, not a bug.  See below https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-6-6-alarm-component.html
"Note: Implementations should carefully consider whether they accept alarm components from untrusted sources, e.g., when importing calendar objects from external sources. One reasonable policy is to always ignore alarm components that the calendar user has not set herself, or at least ask for confirmation in such a case."

Comment: @anmari I see. In the other words, it may a limitation of Office 365. Thanks for your explanation.